# Where do I put my URL routes to prevent an IIS restart?

Tags: asp.net, url, routes

I am writing this code in `global.asax` to save routes

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add("Profile", new Route("Profile/{ID}", new ProfileHandler("~/Member/Profile.aspx")));
```

and then writing this in the handler

```
 var display = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(_virtualPath, typeof(Page)) as Profile;
 //Setting Page Parameters
 display.MemberId = Convert.ToInt32(requestContext.RouteData.Values["ID"]);
```

But I don't like this code. First I am writing hard coded values, and second what if my website is online and I want to republish it? I'll have to stop IIS. Any other ideas to save them?

Answer (score 0):

I've written a whole blog with my own implementation of editable routes. I should make this into a NuGet package. My blog post covers how to have [editable routes](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/17/editable-routes.aspx) without requiring an app domain restart.